# How to map from List[String] to String in Slick 2.0?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, slick, slick-2.0

Because the MySQL database not support Arrays, I want to map lists of strings like `List("facebook","linkedin","local")` to a string like `"facebook, linkedin, local"`.

I want do the bidirectional mapping with slick 2.0, but I do not how to write an instance of `TypeMapper`.

Can anyone provide an example for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented in the official slick doc [here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/migration.html#mapped-column-types).

You can use `MappedColumnType.base[T, U](tmap: (T) ⇒ U, tcomap: (U) ⇒ T)` (see [scaladoc](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.1/api/#scala.slick.profile.RelationalTypesComponent%24MappedColumnTypeFactory)).

It requires two function arguments `tmap` and `tcomap` which do the mapping in both directions.

For your specific use case this could be implemented like such:

```
implicit val stringListMapper = MappedColumnType.base[List[String],String](
  list => list.mkString(","),
  string => string.split(',').toList
)
```

Note that this is not safe because if there are commas contained in the Strings, the mapping is not bijective. You would have to make sure there are none or escape them in some way. I leave this to you.

Comment: this fails if the list is empty, the following slightly different alternative supports empty lists:

```scala
MappedColumnType.base[List[String], String](
    {
      case Nil  => ""
      case list => list.mkString(",")
    }, {
      case ""     => Nil
      case string => string.split(',').toList
    }
  )
```